# Display popup textbox

Tags: javascript, html, textbox

I need some help here. I need to display a popup textbox. For example, there is a quantity that the user need to insert to display textbox :

```
Quantity : 3
```

If the user insert 3, then 3 textbox will be display.

```
ID : (Textbox)
     (Textbox)
     (Textbox)
```

Comment: Is this a homework question? If so, please flag as such.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know what you are doing. If you have any questions feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1):

html:

```
<input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" />
<input type="button" name="btn" id="btn" />
```

js:

```
$(function() {
    $('#btn').click(function() {
        var qty = $('#qty').val();
        if (qty > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < qty; i++) {
                $('body').append('<input type="text" />');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    for(var i=0; i<quantity; i++)
        Alert("your message");
```

Comment: "your message"?For example?I'm sorry, I'm not really good in html or javascript.

Comment: @20151012 am assuming the message you want to display? Anything you want displayed on the screen

Comment: It looks like 20151012 needs the dialog to accept three user inputs (in this case) rather than display a static message three times.